# structs and array incrementation in C

Tags: c#, arrays, c, increment, translate

currently I'm trying to translate some Code from C to C# and I'm running into some problems.
Beacause I'm a C# programmer and have no idea of C I have to ask something here (found nothing that answers my question). I have following piece of Code in C:

```
struct item { short sectorno,sx1,sx2; } queue[MaxQueue], *head=queue, *tail=queue;
short ytop[W]={0}, ybottom[W], renderedsectors[NumSectors];

*head = (struct item) { player.sector, 0, W-1 };

if(++head == queue+MaxQueue) head = queue;

const struct item now = *tail;
    
if(++tail == queue+MaxQueue) tail = queue;
    if(renderedsectors[now.sectorno] & 0x21) continue;
    ++renderedsectors[now.sectorno];
```

I wrote this in C#:

```
        Item[] queue = new Item[MaxQueue];
        Item[] head = queue;
        Item[] tail = queue;

        int[] ytop = new int[W]; //{ 0 };
        int[] ybottom = new int[W];
        int[] renderedsectors = new int[NumSectors];

        for (int x = 0; x < W; ++x)
        {
            ybottom[x] = H - 1;
        }
        for (int n = 0; n < NumSectors; ++n)
        {
            renderedsectors[n] = 0;
        }

        head[0] = new Item { sectorno = player.sector, sx1 = 0, sx2 = W - 1 };
        if (head[1] == queue[queue.Length - 1])
        {
            head = queue;
        }
```

I hope this is correct so far. Now my questions:

What does

```
         short ytop[W]={0}
```

do?
This an array of shorts, right? Is 0 assigned to the first position of the array here? That's what I have figured out from a debugger.

I can't understand following line:

```
         if(++head == queue+MaxQueue) head = queue;
```

Does ++ on the array increments the index of the array? And does queue+32 means the last position of the array? (strange because that would be position 32 which would be out of bounds...)

And the last thing.. what does that mean?

```
         ++renderedsectors[now.sectorno];
```

I would say increments the index of the array but where and how does this get stored?

Thank you very much! I would be glad about some help understanding this C code.

Comment: *"I hope this is correct so far"* -  it's not. You need to learn about pointers if you want to understand the C code. Or you could rewrite it to use indices into the array instead (which is how you would handle it in C#)

Comment: I read somewhere pointers are not needed in C#. Could you rewrite the piece of Code in C to show me what you mean? I mean the solution with the indices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`short ytop[W]={0}` declares `ytop` to be an array of `W` elements of type `short` and explicitly initializes the first of them to zero. The remaining elements are default initialized, which also initializes the elements to zero. (This is an idiom in C because defining an array with `short ytop[W];` inside a function would not initialize it at all; the element values would be indeterminate. Explicitly initializing one of them triggers default initialization of the rest.)

In `if(++head == queue+MaxQueue) head = queue;`, `++head` does two things:

- It increments the stored value of `head`.
- For the purpose of evaluated the rest of the expression, the value of `++head` is the value of `head` with the increment included.

Two notes about this:

- `if(++head == queue+MaxQueue) head = queue;` is largely the same as doing the increment first, `head = head + 1;` and then `if(head == queue+MaxQueue) head = queue;`. However, there are technical details in C semantics that differ; the actual update to memory of the value of `head` is not necessarily synchronous with the evaluation of the expression.
- When one is added to a pointer, the result is a pointer to the next array element in memory, not the next byte in memory. The type of the pointer is used to know what kind of element it points to and how big that element is.

`queue+MaxQueue` produces a pointer that points `MaxQueue` elements beyond where `queue` points. If `queue` is an array or a pointer to the start of an array, and `MaxQueue` is the number of elements in the array, this points to just beyond the last element of the array. That is okay; we are allowed to point to the “end” of the array in this way, to use it as a marker for the end position.

In `++renderedsectors[now.sectorno];`, `renderedsectors[now.sectorno]` is the element of `renderedsectors` that has index `now.sectorno`. The `++` increments its stored value.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have som questions: So head++ increments the position of the array? For example the pointer points to the element at index 0 - ++ points to the index 1? So the value inside does not get affected? Do you mean this with "stored value" ? Same with renderedsectors? And queue+MaxQueue points then to the last element in the array?

Comment: @Canox: An array does not have a position. It is sequence of elements in an array. When `*head` appears in a declaration for the type `struct item { short sectorno,sx1,sx2; }`, it declares `head` to be a pointer to that type. With `*head=queue`, it is declared to be a pointer and is initialized to point to the start of the array. (When an array name is used in code like this [not always], it is automatically converted to a pointer to the first element of the array.) `head` has its own separate existence; it is not “the position” of the array. It is a pointer that can be used and modified.

Comment: @Canox: The stored value of an object is the value that has been written to memory for it.

Comment: @Canox: `queue+MaxQueue` does not point to the last element of the array. It points just beyond the last element, where the next element would be if there were another element.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. That helped a lot to understand the code :)